# Como puedo obtener la fecha minima y maxima de un arreglo en javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, date

Tengo este arreglo:

```
var arr = ["2018-06-07","2018-06-30","2018-06-01","2018-06-21","2018-07-20"];
```

Y necesito sacar la fecha maxima y minima con javascript, eh intentado con esta funcion:

```
var min = new Date(Math.max.apply(null,arr));
var max = new Date(Math.min.apply(null,arr));
```

Pero me devuelven un valor "NaN".

que estare haciendo mal? o hay alguna otra forma de sacar la fecha mayor y menor de un arreglo?, gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El detalle es que estas  buscando el valor minimo y maximo de un string , 
debes cambiar tu arreglo a Date() y no tendras problemas

```js
const arr = ["2018-06-07","2018-06-30","2018-06-01","2018-06-21","2018-07-20"];

let arrayFechas = arr.map((fechaActual) => new Date(fechaActual) );

var max = new Date(Math.max.apply(null,arrayFechas));
var min = new Date(Math.min.apply(null,arrayFechas));

console.log("valor minimo" , min) 
console.log("valor maximo" ,max)
```

Otra opcion pero igual conviertes el array en Date , recorriendolo y que te devuelva un elemento es con [Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/reduce)

```js
const arr = ["2018-06-07","2018-06-30","2018-06-01","2018-06-21","2018-07-20"];

var min = arr.reduce(function (valor1, valor2) { return new Date(valor1) <  new Date(valor2) ? valor1 : valor2; }); 
var max = arr.reduce(function (valor1, valor2) { return new Date(valor1) > new Date(valor2) ? valor1 : valor2; });

console.log("valor minimo" , min) 
console.log("valor maximo" ,max)
```

Comment: Ok esta segunda opcion fue la que me ayudo, gracias.

Answer (score 2):

Usando la clase `Date` de JavaScript puedes hacerlo fácilmente pues te permite hacer operaciones de comparación con las fechas y hacer fechas a partir de strings. 
Entonces solo es cuestión de iterar el arreglo e ir guardando los mayores o menores.

```js
var arr = ["2018-06-07","2018-06-30","2018-06-01","2018-06-21","2018-07-20"];

var mayorDate= new Date(arr[0]);
var menorDate= new Date(arr[0]);

for (var i = 0; i<arr.length; i++){
 var arrDate= new Date(arr[i]);
 if(arrDate > mayorDate){
   mayorDate=arrDate
  }
  if(arrDate < menorDate){
   menorDate=arrDate
  }
}

console.log("Fecha mayor: "+mayorDate.toUTCString());
console.log("Fecha menor: "+menorDate.toUTCString());
```

Answer (score 2):

Deberías hacer lo siguiente:

```js
    var dates = [];
    dates.push(new Date("2011/06/25"))
    dates.push(new Date("2011/06/26"))
    dates.push(new Date("2011/06/27"))
    dates.push(new Date("2011/06/28"))
    var max = new Date(Math.max(...dates));
    var min = new Date(Math.min(...dates));
    console.log(max);
    console.log(min);
```

Prueba esto desde tu consola del navegador, te deberia funcionar luego lo adecuas a tus necesidades, en este caso colocas las fechas que corresponden.

Comment: Hola, la pregunta requiere que se conviertan las fechas de _string_ a _date_.

Comment: la idea es que expliques por que le falla y das tu solucion